# ASP.NET Identity with MySql problem after publishing to IIS server

Tags: mysql, asp.net, iis, asp.net-identity, publish

I made a ASP.NET Web Api. I have my connection string inside web.config and it looks like this:

```
<add name="AuthContext" connectionString="Data Source=*****; Initial Catalog=*****;Uid=*****;Pwd=****;SslMode=None;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

This database is also on external server and can be reached from anywhere.
On my local machine everythings works completely fine, but when i publish it to exteral IIS server i get that error:

```
"The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.",
```

and also this:

```
"InnerException": {
        "Message": "An error has occurred.",
        "ExceptionMessage": "Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.",
        "ExceptionType": "System.ArgumentException",
        "StackTrace": "   at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)\r\n   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DependencyResolution.DefaultProviderFactoryResolver.GetService(Type type, Object key, Func`3 handleFailedLookup)"
    }
```

I would like to know why during connecting to dabase with for example ADO.NET i have to use

```
SslMode=None
```

In other case i get that error:

[image: SSL Error]

it means handshake failed, unexpected package format
Also i get another error in another controller and also only in IIS:
[image: second error]

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so in my web.config i added:

```
<system.data>
   <DbProviderFactories>
     <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
     <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" 
          type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=8.0.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
   </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

and than everything worked fine